# Can/Should custom $resource action methods be tested?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jasmine

In a angular service I have $resource action methods such as :

```
class FooService {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($resource) {
    this.Foo = $resource('/foo/:fooId/',
                          {fooId: '@fooId'},
                          {
                             bar: {
                                method: 'GET',
                                url: '/foo/:fooId/bar/',
                                isArray: true
                          }
                );
  }
  getAllFoo() {
    return this.Foo.query();
  }
}
```

is bar testable ?

I already have tests for methods such as getAllFoo(), but I am not so sure about $resource action methods.

Is it ok to use them directly in controller, as in
`this.FooService.Foo.bar(params).$promise.then` ?

Should they be tested ?
And if so, how ?

EDIT:
I know how to test getAllFoo() :

```
describe('FooService', () => {
    let $rootScope, $resource, $httpBackend, $log, $interval;
    let makeFooService, translateMock;
    let mockAllFoo = [
        {"id": 123,"stuff": "asdf asdf"},
        {"id": 124,"stuff": "hjghjg"}
    ];

    beforeEach(window.module(FooModule.name));

    beforeEach(inject((_$rootScope_, $q, _$resource_, _$httpBackend_, _$log_) => {   
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        queryDeferred = $q.defer();
        $resource = _$resource_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $log = _$log_;   
        translateMock = { use: () => ({}) };  
        makeFooService = () =>  new FooService(_$resource_);
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
    describe('Service', () => {
    it('has a resource-property [Foo]', () => {
        let service = makeFooService();
        expect(service.Foo).not.toBeNull();
    });

    it('should load all foos when getAllFoo() is called', () => {
        $httpBackend.expect('GET', /(.+)\/foo/).respond( () => [200, mockAllFoo, 'success'] );
        let service = makeFooService();
        let allFoo = service.getAllFoo();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(allFoo.length).toBe(2);
    });
```

So I know how to test getAllFoo() but not how to test bar();
If bar is testable and usable in a controller directly, then I dont see the point of doing methods such as getAllFoo() that are simply wrapper around $resource action methods. I need clarifications on the best practices here.

Comment: I JUST HAD A TYPO in my code, $resource action methods are testable, no problem with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good idea test resources, some resource can have response transformers or some logic to create the URL request. Angular provides $httpBackend to performer test in http requests being able to mock the http response.

Mock the request

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', '/foo').respond({foo: 'bar'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});
```

Release the HTTP response

```
$httpBackend.flush();
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Yes, In my option there is no needed to create a "wrapper" only if you need do some logic before call the actual resource.

In order to test "bar" you will need do something similar to the following code:

```
it('should call the correct url and handler the response right', (done)=>{
    $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/foo/bar_id/bar/').respond( () => [200, {'id': 124,'stuff': 'hjghjg'}, 'success'] );
    let service = makeFooService();

    service.bar({fooId: 'bar_id'}).$promise.then(result =>{
        expect(result).toEqual({'id': 124,'stuff': 'hjghjg'});
        done();
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Also I think it's okay call the resource method directly from the controller. $resource provides a particular functionality that you don't need treat the promise, you can assign the response value directly to a var like:

```
var bar = this.FooService.Foo.bar(params);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Thx for answering. I edited the question, I am familiar with $httpBackend, and would happily use it to test FooService.Foo.bar, but it is not available in my test setup when I do let service = makeFooService(); - I know neither how to test those service methods directly, nor how to test controllers who use them (more important). As a workaround I could create a method in the service: getBar() {return this.Foo.bar(); } but this feel way less elegant

Comment: Thanks for the help, the ridiculous truth in the end is that I did not properly import the module in the test, hence the methods not found.